# Adding the original file as a header in a flow

Tags: spring-integration

I have an Integration flow that handles a method. After pulling a file from FTP server to local, this method reads the csv file ex: foo.csv and creates a new file bar.csv, then bar.csv is ftpd to FTP server again, I'm thinking of a solution to change the name of foo.csv to lets say foo_10012019.csv and send it again to FTP server to a History folder downstream and delete it from local, how can I do this? I saw that we can use FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE but not sure how I can use it, I have created an advice that will delete the payload of the flow but the payload is the new generated file bar.csv, can I use the same flow in the outbound to send the original file and change its name to the FTP server? Function name is localToFtpFlow that I'm using to send the new file bar.csv

Below is the code I have.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan
public class FTIntegration {

public static final String TIMEZONE_UTC = "UTC";
public static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
public static final String TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX = ".part";
public static final int POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY = 5000;
public static final int MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL = 100;


private DataSource dataSource;

//private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTIntegration.class);
private static final Logger LOG1 = Logger.getLogger(FTIntegration.class);
private static final String CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE = "intermediateChannel";

private static final String OUTBOUND_CHANNEL = "outboundChannel";

/* pulling the server config from postgres DB*/

private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

@Autowired
private CSVToCSVNoQ csvToCSVNoQ;

public FTIntegration(BranchRepository branchRepository) {
    this.branchRepository = branchRepository;
}

@Bean
public Branch myBranch() {
    return new Branch();
}

/**
 * The default poller with 5s, 100 messages, RotatingServerAdvice and transaction.
 *
 * @return default poller.
 */
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers
            .fixedDelay(POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY)
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .transactional()
            .get();
}

/**
 * The direct channel for the flow.
 *
 * @return MessageChannel
 */
@Bean
public MessageChannel stockIntermediateChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

/**
 * Get the files from a remote directory. Add a timestamp to the filename
 * and write them to a local temporary folder.
 *
 * @return IntegrationFlow
 */

@Bean
public PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store() {
    PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
    return store;
}

public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(Branch myBranch) throws IOException {

    final FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sourceSpecFtp = Ftp.inboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch))
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            //.patternFilter("*.csv")
            .maxFetchSize(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
            .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath())
            .regexFilter("FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv")
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .localDirectory(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
            .temporaryFileSuffix(TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX)


            /*.localFilenameExpression(new FunctionExpression<String>(s -> {
                final int fileTypeSepPos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
                return DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES)
                        .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC))
                        .format(Instant.now())
                        + "_"
                        + s.substring(0,fileTypeSepPos)
                        + s.substring(fileTypeSepPos);
            }))*/;

    // Poller definition
    final Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> stockInboundPoller = endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer
            .id("stockInboundPoller")
            .autoStartup(true)
            .poller(poller());

    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(sourceSpecFtp, stockInboundPoller)

            .transform(File.class, p -> {
                // log step
                LOG1.info("flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: " + p);
                return p;
            })
            .handle(m -> {
                try {
                    this.csvToCSVNoQ.writeCSVfinal("test", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv", myBranch.getBranchCode() + "/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv");
                    LOG1.info("Writing final file .csv " + m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            .get();

    return flow;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow stockIntermediateStageChannel() {
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
            .transform(p -> {
                //log step
                LOG1.info("flow=stockIntermediateStageChannel, message=rename file: " + p);

                return p;
            })
            //TODO
            .channel(new NullChannel())
            .get();

    return flow;

}

/*
* Creating the outbound adaptor to send files from local to FTP server
*
* */


public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                            .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv"))
                            // .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("FEFOexport"+ myBranch.getBranchCode() +".csv"))
                            .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),//FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
 .enrichHeaders(h ->h.header("file_originalFile","FEFOexport" + 
myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv",true))

            .transform(p -> {
                LOG1.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());

                return p;
            })
            .log()
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))

            .get();
}

@Bean
public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    //advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload.delete() + ' was successful'");
    //advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch) {
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
    factory.setUsername(branch.getUsern());
    factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
    factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow success(){
    return f -> f.transform("payload.inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile']")

            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter( createNewFtpSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory("/ftp/erbranch/edms/fefo/History")

            .get());

                          // f.handle(System.out::println);
}

2019-02-04 09:39:39.523  INFO 11748 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\finalBEY.csv, id=6df10c36-262e-3c8a-7ebf-121ecb4c8bf8, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1549265979523}]]
2019-02-04 09:39:39.525  INFO 11748 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\finalBEY.csv, id=b6ec5ecc-f746-978d-51a1-62c3b0b8c60b, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1549265979524}]
2019-02-04 09:39:40.618  INFO 11748 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully transferred to: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing
2019-02-04 09:39:41.052  INFO 11748 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession   : File has been successfully renamed from: /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv.writing to /ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/finalBEY.csv
AdviceMessage [payload=true was successful, headers={id=54f13c8b-ec50-6389-e5ea-c399184d1c41, timestamp=1549265981055}, inputMessage=GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\finalBEY.csv, id=b6ec5ecc-f746-978d-51a1-62c3b0b8c60b, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1549265979524}]]
```

After Debugging:

```
2019-02-06 12:54:23.708 DEBUG 4060 --- [ask-scheduler-3] i.h.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor : SpEL Expression evaluation failed with EvaluationException.

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'inputMessage' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:58) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:116) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:371) ~[spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:128) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.java:105) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.evaluateSuccessExpression(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:248) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.doInvoke(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:214) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:70) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.handleMessage(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) [spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:220) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277) [spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:378) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:372) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is very hard to read because it has no indentation - can you repost the code with proper indentation? Also, show the integration flow that consumes from the `success.input` channel - that's where the secondary operation will be performed.

The message sent to the success channel is an `AdviceMessage`; so the flow would have a tranformer with something like `payload.inputMessage.headers['file_originalMessage']` which can then be sent to FTP.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code to show indentation better, also added the success flow where it just print out the payload , I did not  understand what exactly to be done in the success flow, should I open a new outbound adapter or what should be there? also from the printout of the success I can see that the file_originalFile is the final output that im sending already to the FTP (ex bar.csv) while I want to send the foo.csv in which the bar.csv is created from, hope I'm more clear in what I need to do, i pasted also the output of the consol.@Gary Russell

Comment: As I said in the answer; `.transform()` the advice message to the original file; then send it to a second FTP outbound adapter `.transform(...).handle(anotherFTPadapter)`. You need to explicitly set the original file header.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my success method as to what I have understood from your guidance, I'm sure I did not get it right as still nothing has been FTPd on the success...trying to find out the way on doing so, am I on the correct path on getting this right?Sorry but bear with me as I'm still learning how spring integration works@Gary russell

Comment: This `headers['BEY/FEFOexportBEY.csv']` is wrong - there is no such header - right? It should be `headers['file_originalFile']`. Best way to debug is turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages flowing between components.

Comment: Correct there is no such header, why I used this is because the AdviceMessage has finalBEY.csv as file_originalFile while I want to send back the first file that I used to generate finalBEY.csv which is FEFOexportBEY.csv and I cannot see that in the AdviceMessage...will try also to debug to see if I can spot what is happening @Gary Russell

Comment: I turned on Debugging and got an exception (SpEL Expression evaluation failed with EvaluationException.) I pasted above the error I got but was not able to find the solution, any suggestion on that?thanks @Gary Russell

Comment: You need to pay more attention to the logs and the exception. See the log earlier showing the `AdviceMessage` - it has 3 properties `payload`, `headers` and `inputMessage`. The `inputMessage` is a property of the `Message` **not the `payload`**. `f.transform("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile']")`.

Comment: This worked smoothly now, it is sending the original file in the inputMessage that is the bar.csv , I want it to point to the foo.csv instead of the bar.csv, can I do so?bar.csv is already being sent from the first outboundadapter and the success channel is not finding it when I'm sending the adviceMessage since already sent @Gary Russell

Comment: After the `Files.inboundChannelAdapter()` add `.enrichHeaders(...)` with overwrite=true to replace the header with a different value (or use a different header altogether).

Comment: Works smooth with the enrichHeaders, I updated the code @Gary Russell